# Add Stroke to Top of Holo Button Without using solid in a drawable

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to add a stroke to the top of a Holo button, my application allows theme change from Holo --> Holo.Light. Every piece of information I have found relates to providing a solid in a custom drawable. Is there a way to keep all the holo themed buttons intact and just add a stroke to the top of particular buttons?

Basically I want to keep the colors Holo/Light have but just add a stroke at the top.

Sample:

[image: Sample Look]

Tried drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners android:radius="6dp" />
<solid android:colorBackground="#00000000" />
<stroke android:width="2px" android:color="#050875">
</stroke>
</shape>
```

This when applied as a background overrides the Holo/Light colors to transparent background.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried and explain how your results differ from the intended results. Please read this [advice on how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to follow the link at the bottom to Jon Skeet's blog post [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). Pay special attention to the "Golden Rule"

Answer (score 0):

What you should do, is create a drawable (with a colored stroke), like you described.  You can then make the regulars solid color transparent color (#00000000) and apply it as a background to the view component you wish to style.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, unfortunately using a transparent color as the solid overrides the holo buttons colors was not workable, any further help would be much appreciated.